# How to add a loop to another loop?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I have the script below that is functioning. 
But, I would like to have a loop for taking as y, different variables that are in columns; in this example : Petal.length and Petal.width.
Since, there is already a loop in this script, I don't know how to add one.

```
data <-iris
uniq_species = unique(data$Species)
plot_list = list()
for (i in uniq_species) {
  temp_plot = ggplot(data= subset(data, Species == i),aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, colour=Species)) + 
    geom_boxplot()+ ggtitle(i)
  plot_list[[i]] =temp_plot}
pdf("y=Sepal Width per species.pdf")
for (i in uniq_species) {
  print(plot_list[[i]])}
dev.off()
```

Comment: How would you like to save the output? As a separate pdf-file, or just more pages in the same pdf? How would you like to store the plots? And why do you want to store them in a list? You could also just print them directly without the need to store them.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility should be to set the pdf file before and then have both contents in the same for loop:

```
plot_list = list()
pdf("y=Sepal Width per species.pdf")
for (i in uniq_species) {
temp_plot <- ggplot(data = subset(data, Species == i), aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
geom_boxplot() + ggtitle(i)
plot_list[[i]] <- temp_plot
print(plot_list[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```